# Check if symlink is broken or doesn't exist

Tags: shell-script, symlink, test

Trying to make an `if` statement that checks if a file is a valid symlink (meaning it also exists).

I tried:

```
[ -h "$1" -a ! -e "$1" ]
```

... buut it doesn't work. I want to execute code if the file isn't a valid symlink, or doesn't exist at all.

Comment: You are using 6 arguments for test and more than 4 args are unspecified. Better divide it into more single purpose tests.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the name in `$1` is a valid symbolic link, then the `-e` test would be true. If it's a broken symbolic link, then the `-e` test would fail. The test would additionally fail if the name in `$1` does not exist at all.

So, to test whether `$1` is a broken symbolic link, *or* if it doesn't exist at all, it would be enough to use

```
if [ ! -e "$1" ]; then ...; fi
```

The test that you have is better written without the [deprecated](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html#tag_20_128_16) `-a` as

```
if [ ! -e "$1" ] && [ -h "$1" ]; then ...; fi
```

This tests whether `$1` is an existing broken symbolic link.

Would you want to test for a valid symbolic link, use

```
if [ -e "$1" ] && [ -h "$1" ]; then ...; fi
```

Comment: It might depend on the version, but on my machine (GNU core utils 8.32) `-e` does not check whether the link is broken. It returns true as long as the link file itself exists.

Comment: @ThomasH The `-e` test is handled by the shell, which is not part of coreutils (it would be `bash` or `dash` or `zsh` or some other shell).  The shell would in turn implement the semantics imposed by the POSIX standard on the `-e` test, which requires the test to resolve any symbolic links and to fail if the given pathname can't be resolved. If your shell's `-e` test returns _true_ for a broken symbolic link, then this is a bug in that shell.