# How do I resolve a relative path in a POSIX shell if readlink/realpath is not available?

Tags: shell-script, scripting, path, posix, readlink

If neither utility `readlink`, nor `realpath` is available (I think today mostly from GNU coreutils?), what can I use in POSIX shell scripting to resolve a relative path?

There is a [`realpath`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/realpath.html) C function, though. So maybe one of the other [utilities](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/idx/utilities.html) uses it secretly?

Comment: perl has a core module (i.e. included with perl) called [Cwd](https://metacpan.org/pod/Cwd) that includes a `realpath()` function.  You could re-implement a very basic realpath utility in about 3 lines of perl (shebang, `use Cwd;`, and calling the realpath function).  A more complete re-implementation would probably be 10-20 lines including option handling.  Or write a basic realpath util in C. Or some other language with a similar library/function.  Alternatively, just install GNU coreutils in /usr/local/GNU or somewhere (so they don't conflict with the native utils from your posix system)

Comment: Actually, here's a one-liner that you could easily use as an alias or shell function:`perl -MCwd=realpath -le 'print realpath(shift)'`.  Sample run: in my home dir, ~/.steam is a symlink to /var/games/steam - if I run `perl -MCwd=realpath -le 'print realpath(shift)' ~/.steam`, the output is `/var/games/steam`.   And here's a version that handles multiple pathname args: `perl -MCwd=realpath -le 'foreach (@ARGV) {print realpath $_}'`.   BTW, the `-MCwd=realpath` argument use the `-M` option to tell perl to use the Cwd module and import the realpath function.

Comment: See also: [Unix-portable way to get script's absolute path in zsh?](//unix.stackexchange.com/a/136565)

Answer (score 3):

> There is a [`realpath`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/realpath.html) C function, though. So maybe one of the other [utilities](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/idx/utilities.html) uses it secretly?

From the top of my head, I'm not aware any of those utilities reference the `realpath` function in their specification.

What I know is that [*test*](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html) for directory entries often returns true when a *pathname is resolved to an existing directory entry* ¹ + x.

Peeking into the implementation in *dash(git.kernel.org)*, it uses *lstat64/stat64*.

This may suffice for directories (*test **-d** pathname*) to [*cd*](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/cd.html) into them and return the resolved pathname with [*pwd*](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/pwd.html).

For *cd*, *CDPATH* should be unset or empty², and the operand should not be the hyphen-minus *"-"*.³

```
([ -d "$1" ] && [ '-' != "$1" ] && CDPATH= cd -P -- "$1" && pwd -P)
```

*Example:* Return a directories absolute, normalized and physical pathname, null if it does not resolve to a directory.

If it is an issue to exclude the hyphen-minus ("-") as pathname, an alternative is to set the operand to "./-" for this specific case.

¹ cf. *test*;
² cf. *cd step 5 description*,
³ cf. *cd "-" operand*

---

As I could read, you're already aware of *dirname* and *basename*, perhaps also about how to *[check if [a] symlink [(symbolic link)] is broken or doesn't exist <sup>Unix&Linux</sup>](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/586346/9340)*, and if not, see there if it is of interest in the context of this answers' *test* usage, e.g. to differentiate on a *test -d pathname* exit status of 1.

Answer (score 1):

Since posting the question, I came up with the following workaround:

```
#!/bin/sh
realpath() (
    file=
    path=$1
    [ -d "$path" ] || {
        file=/$(basename -- "$path")
        path=$(dirname -- "$path")
    }
    {
        path=$(cd -- "$path" && pwd)$file
    } || exit $?
    printf %s\\n "/${path#"${path%%[!/]*}"}"
)
```

Warning: Obviously, I haven't been able to test this much so far! Always looking for feedback. If you see something, please leave a comment.

Also, I'm sure someone else has had the same idea before and has solved it much better, especially for edge cases and with extensive testing. Please post a link if you know more.

The above shell function `realpath` is a replacement for GNU coreutils `realpath -s --`, see https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/realpath-invocation.html. Which means that there is no resolving of symbolic links. (Which is also not necessary if we're only interested in resolving a relative path.)

- ```
  #!/bin/sh
  ```

  Use shebang for POSIX shell.
- ```
  realpath() (
  ```

  Run the function in a subshell, i.e. `realpath() (...)` instead of `realpath() {...}`, so we don't overwrite possibly existing variables `file` and `path`. (POSIX shell doesn't support local variables.)
- ```
  file=
  path=$1
  ```

  Define variables. Initially assume that the path given by argument `$1` is an existing directory. (Which is important, because the last component of the path might be `.` or `..`, which is the relative part of the path that we want to eliminate.)
- ```
  [ -d "$path" ] || {
      file=/$(basename -- "$path")
      path=$(dirname -- "$path")
  }
  ```

  In case the function argument was not a path to an existing directory as previously assumed, we have to adjust `$path`. To quote from `man realpath`:

  > Print the resolved absolute file name; all but the last component must exist

  So it doesn't really matter if `$file` (the "last component") is actually an existing file or a non-existing file or folder - we'll just cut it from `$path` for now (and append it again, eventually).
- ```
  {
      path=$(cd -- "$path" && pwd)$file
  ```

  This is where the "trick" happens: To resolve any relative paths, we just let `cd` resolve them for us and use `pwd` to print the directory where we end up. This new path is being saved in `$path`. Also, we don't have to worry about accidentally actually changing our cwd because [2.6.3 Command Substitution](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html) runs in a subshell. `$file` gets appended at the end.
- ```
  } || exit $?
  ```

  This line is the reason for the `{...}` code block around the variable assignment from the previous line. In case the user provided a faulty path (e.g. more than just the last component doesn't exist), `cd` (from inside the command substitution) should fail and print an error message to stderr (e.g. "can't cd to ...") and exit with an error code > 0. This will also be the error code for the command substitution subshell. To access this error code as `$?`, the variable assignment gets wrapped by `{...}`. So in case the `{...}` block fails, we exit the function and propagate the same non-zero error code.
- ```
  printf %s\\n "/${path#"${path%%[!/]*}"}"
  ```

  Because of edge cases like `//` or `/a` where `a` doesn't exist, we would end up with result `//` or `//a`. So [2.6.2 Parameter Expansion](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_02) is being used to remove all leading slashes from `$path`, before prepending a single slash for the final output.

Here are some tests that I ran:

```
for path in / // /// . .. "$HOME/." "$HOME/.." "*" --help /tmp /notexisting
do
    if [ "$(realpath "$path")" != "$(/usr/bin/realpath -s -- "$path")" ]
    then
        printf %s\\n "$path"
    fi
done
```

Comment: I came up with something similar and [placed an answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/749916/9340), specifically looking into `cd ... pwd`. It is merely the same, however CDPATH should be taken into account and I've skipped `--`  (now as I see it in your answer), I think I should have made use of that, too, but have not tested with it yet. And `-` is special operand for _cd_ according to the referenced specs. And then you may also probably want to handle broken symbolic links, I left a reference for that in my answer as well. And you can resolve symbolic links with `pwd -P`,  sort of.